# conditional passing functions as props to a component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have this breadcrump component that map over props and renders a list of chip components like this:

```
class BreadCrumb extends React.Component {
    render () {
      const {
        steps,
        activeIndex
      } = this.props;

      const chips = steps
        .map((step,index) => {

          return <Chip 
                  key={index} 
                  title={step.category} 
                  onClick = {()=> this.props.selectChip(index)}   // this should be passed only if 
                                                                  //                active == true
                  active={activeIndex >= index} />
              })

      return (
        <div className="chip-container">
            {chips}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

i need to click on chips only if his active prop is true,
this is the chip component

```
class Chip extends React.Component {
    render(){
      const {
        active,
        title
      } = this.props;

      const activeClassName = active ? 'chip active' : 'chip';

      return (
        <div 
            className = {activeClassName}
            onClick = {() => this.props.onClick()} >  
              <span>{title}</span>
        </div>
      )

    }
  }
```

how can i make chip clickable only if the active prop is true?

For further information selectChip() function sets the state of a component App, parent of Breadcrump component, so it is binded to App component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either execute the handler or an empty `function`

```
onClick = {isActive ? this.props.onClick : () =>{} } >
```

Comment: It's better to avoid arrow functions inside JSX due to performance downshifts

Comment: If the component isn't memoized this won't be an issue. But it's a good point

Comment: this works thx, but i'm not sure what is going on here about  :  ( )   =>  { }

Comment: It's a definition of an anonymous function. The equivalent of: `function(){}`. Just a function which returns nothing.

Answer (score 4):

You could e.g. make that `onClick` function as a class method and use a simple condition inside:

```
class Chip extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
       if (this.props.active) {
          this.props.onClick(); // call only if active props is true
       }
    }

    render() {
      const { active, title } = this.props;

      const activeClassName = active ? 'chip active' : 'chip';

      return (
        <div 
            className = {activeClassName}
            onClick = {this.handleClick}
        >  
            <span>{title}</span>
        </div>
      )

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:-

```
// If chip component expects a function all the time
<Chip 
    key={index} 
    title={step.category} 
    onClick = {step.active ? ()=> this.props.selectChip(index) : () => {}}
    active={activeIndex >= index} />

// If onClick is an optional prop to chip component
<Chip 
    key={index} 
    title={step.category} 
    onClick = {step.active ? ()=> this.props.selectChip(index) : undefined}
    active={activeIndex >= index} />
```

Answer (score -1):

// of onClick handler is optional, possibly an alternative solution

```
type ChipProps = {
  title: string;
  active: boolean;
  onClick?: ()=>void;
}

<Chip 
  key={index} 
  title={step.category}  
  active={activeIndex >= index} 
  {...(step.active ? {onClick:()=> this.props.selectChip(index)} : {})}
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).